# Can a person possess a enhanced non drivers id and a Real Id at the same time?

Tags: real-id

Right now I currently have a NY standard Non Driver Id and a FL Real Id Non Driver Id. I know that a person cannot have two Real Ids or else the older id will get terminated. I opted out for the Enhanced when I applied for the NY id because I didn’t know what would happen if I took it. From what I have seen online, I think the enhanced is a completely different document than the Federal Real Id as the enhanced is similar to the passport card. It would make my life easier crossing the Canadian border as I don’t have a passport card. The documents needed for the enhanced are not an issue for me. I wouldn’t want the Enhanced to terminate my florida id.

Comment: How do you *legally* have ID's from 2 different states? I know that for driver licenses you need to hand in the previous one when you permanently move to a new state.  Also you can't cross the border with just a Real ID. See [here](https://www.dhs.gov/real-id/real-id-faqs)

Comment: Well they are both non driver id’s as I just tag with family and friends that want to go upstate to Canada whenever they do. Maybe at a later point I will get a drivers license though. Thats why I wanted to know if someone could have a Real Id and an enhanced id at the same time while both being valid since an enhanced isn’t technically a Real Id.

Comment: You need to be a resident of a state or country to have their driver's license or state ID. How are you a resident of both states?

Comment: Well my family has a house in florida and a house in florida that’s like a vacation house. We go to florida and back to NY many times a year. One day I just decided to get the Florida Non driver id and that worked out fine then shortly after I got the NY non driver id. The dmv rep for NY said that you did not even need to provide proof of residency for a standard id but he said if you wanted a real id or enhanced you had to. The question I’m trying to ask is if a enhanced document type is subject to the Real Id rule about you can only have one Federal Real Id at a time or is it excluded?

Comment: @user102008 Your comment may be correct for the US, but not for all countries as you are implying. Some countries issue ids to their citizens indepentent of residence, some countries issue ids to their residents independent of the citizenship and some countries do not issue ids at all.

Comment: @perfectlymint: You need proof that you are a resident of the state for standard IDs in every state. You provided proof of residence for both states by providing some mail to your address in that state, since you have addresses in both states. That may or may not have been legally correct since you might not be considered a resident of the state even though you have an address there.

Comment: What benefit is there in having both of these documents?  What can you do with the Florida ID that you can't do with the New York ID? What can you do with the New York ID that you can't do with the Florida ID?

Comment: @PeterM That's not accurate. There is no Federal law limiting to 1 license, it's a state matter. States that join the Drivers License Compact are supposed to have 1 license, but 4 states are not members. To complicate things, states use the [AAMVA S2S](https://www.aamva.org/technology/systems/driver-licensing-systems/state-to-state-verification-service-(s2s)) system to cancel other licenses, and 12 states currently do participate. Finally, it's a state issue whether the old one is surrendered or cancelled, states may not do this due to the possibility the issuance of the new license is denied.

Comment: @phoog Well, you are correct that either state's document can be used for almost the same purposes. The only difference is that the enhanced NY ID can be used to cross the border. But I already have both of them, so I just wanted to know if I could upgrade my NY standard nondriver ID to an enhanced one and keep the FL Real ID since I already have it. I can't find any clear information if a person can have an enhanced ID and a Real ID at the same time other than the Real ID is a federal standard and the enhanced was made for border state residents to easily go across the border.